# conditional missing value imputation

Tags: r, zoo

How do you impute missing values only if it is 2 or less consecutive missing values and leave other missing values as NAs using na.locf in R? 
E.g.,

```
x<-c(2,1,NA,4,4,NA,NA,NA)
```

The output should be like

```
2,1,1,4,4,NA,NA,NA
```

The first NA is imputed by the previous available "1" and last 3 NAs should not be imputed.

Comment: use `na.locf()` from the package `zoo`

Answer (score 5):

`na.locf` from `zoo` has a 'maxgap' argument so you can simply do:

```
library(zoo)

na.locf(x, maxgap = 2, na.rm = FALSE)
[1]  2  1  1  4  4 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create groups, use `ave` to count `length` of each group and use `na.locf` only when the the value is `NA` and `length` of the group is less than equal to 2.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

ifelse(ave(x, rleid(x), FUN = length) <= 2 & is.na(x), na.locf(x), x)
#[1]  2  1  1  4  4 NA NA NA
```